# Cloudflare ssl error showing "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, whm

I am trying to add CloudFlare free ssl on dedicated server based(WHM). I am getting warning in Chrome "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".
[cloudflare ssl error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ50c.png)
1. I have updated the Name Server(almost 24 hours ago) and Cloudflare is showing *This website is active on Cloudflare*.
2. Even Page Rules is not working on CloudFlare.
3. Checking the website on whatsmydns.net shows CloudFlare IPs.

Comment: Can you provide the CF rules you are currently using? Also, what platform do you use for your website?

Answer (score 1):

Turn CloudFlare on for that domain, i.e. the cloud needs to be orange

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks ;-)